# Quart application - "No WebSocket UPGRADE"?

Tags: python, websocket, discord.py, quart

I am coding a discord bot and running a Quart Server asyncronously. Everything was fine, until this error popped up:

```
No WebSocket UPGRADE hdr: None
 Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket".
```

app/app.py:

```
from quart import Quart, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Quart(__name__)

app.route...
```

main.py:

```
from app.app import app
from src.bot import MyBot
...

# MyBot extends discord.ext.commands.Bot
client = MyBot(command_prefix='rr', intents=Intents.all())

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.loop.create_task(app.run_task(host="0.0.0.0", debug=False))
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Can anyone help me fix it or at least understand it?

P.S.: I am using replit to run my code.